# getting unique constraint failed in sqlalchemy after taking out unique requirement and migrating

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I made a model in sqlite with a column name which had the property unique=True. Later I decided I wanted to drop this property so I changed it to unique=False but am getting the following error as if I never made the change.

Error:

```
IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: group.name [SQL: u'INSERT INTO "group" (name, timestamp, parent_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'DOW', None, None)]
```

old model.py

```
class Group(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False, unique=True)
    timestamp=db.Column(db.DateTime)
    permissions=db.relationship('Permission', backref='group')
    roles=db.relationship('Role', backref='group')
    messages=db.relationship('Message', backref='group')

    message_groups=db.relationship('Message_Group', backref='group')
    message_users=db.relationship('Message_User', backref='group')
    parent_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
    children=db.relationship('Group', backref=db.backref('parent', remote_side=[id]))
    #users backrefs User
```

new model.py

```
class Group(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False, unique=False)
    timestamp=db.Column(db.DateTime)
    permissions=db.relationship('Permission', backref='group')
    roles=db.relationship('Role', backref='group')
    messages=db.relationship('Message', backref='group')

    message_groups=db.relationship('Message_Group', backref='group')
    message_users=db.relationship('Message_User', backref='group')
    parent_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
    children=db.relationship('Group', backref=db.backref('parent', remote_side=[id]))
    #users backrefs User
```

Here are the migration scripts I used to upgrade the database after making the change to name

db_migrate.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
import imp
from migrate.versioning import api
from app import db
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
migration = SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO + ('/versions/%03d_migration.py' % (v+1))
tmp_module = imp.new_module('old_model')
old_model = api.create_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
exec old_model in tmp_module.__dict__
script = api.make_update_script_for_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
                                          SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO,
                                          tmp_module.meta, db.metadata)
open(migration, "wt").write(script)
api.upgrade(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
print('New migration saved as ' + migration)
print('Current database version: ' + str(v))
```

db_upgrade.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
api.upgrade(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
print('Current database version: ' + str(v))
```

Feel free to judge my model and offer tips to make it faster. I am still pretty new to sql.

Comment: Are you sure your upgrade script is actually working/finishing? Do you see any errors or warnings when you perform the upgrade? This may be an issue with using SQLite3. SQLite does not support `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT` and there is a lot of [nuances](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/batch.html#including-unnamed-unique-constraints) with SQLite and unique constraints. The official SQLAlchemy Migrate docs state that there is only partial support for these migrations with sqlite through a workaround. You may be encountering one of these nuances -- If you can, try another dialect.

Comment: I ran the script more than once to no avail and did not see any errors. I dug back through my migration.py scripts and it isn't changing the column setting for it even though I explicately stated unique=False. At this point I kind of want to migrate the data to a fresh database and go from there. Do you have a suggested way of doing this?